# performance issue when using WHERE EXISTS condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that hold GBs of data.

When I perform a query with "WHERE EXISTS ...", on either table, the whole MySQL goes down.

Example of the query:

```
DELETE FROM `records`  
where exists (
    select * 
    from `measurements` 
    where `file_id` = 17
    and measurements.id = records.measurement_id
    )
```

I am not sure on where to start debugging or how this can be solved.

Example of a query which works fine on the same server running on a different database, but takes forever on the main DB

```
select * 
from `params` 
where exists (
    select * 
    from `records` 
    where `params`.`record_id` = `records`.`id` and exists (
        select * 
        from `measurements` 
        where `records`.`measurement_id` = `measurements`.`id`
            and `file_id` = 17"
    )
)
```

Comment: Correlation is needed on the subquery & use 1 instead of *  You don't need any values on the select and returning the columns never to use them seems to be wasteful; especially if you have lots of columns in that table.  Also do you have an index on File_ID and measurements.id?

Comment: I have adjusted the query in my post, thanks for pointing it out, but the DB is still going down.

Comment: Indexes on file_ID, measurements.id and records.measurement_Id?  Also lots of indexes on records?  If so, the delete has to manage all the indexes.  you may need to disable them then rebuild after delete is done. if you have lots of indexes and records in "records"

Comment: I have index on measurements.file_id and records.mesaurement_id. measurements.id and records.id are both primary keys. I find if I do query within exists() everything is ok. Same applies to when I delete a selection of record. However when I utilise exists() to do a selection or delete I have problems.

Comment: and if you just select the records using exists does it complete quickly? `SELECT * FROM records where exists...`(how many records 2155?) if so I think it' the index management for the volume of records being deleted.  So disabling the indexes and then enabling after delete completes and refrehsing may be the answer.

Comment: I find that even select is dead slow when selection is broad

Comment: Indexes themselves corrupt?  Rebuild the indexes that this query would use?  What's the explain plan show?  Should help with bottleneck isolation.

Comment: I have 65 Kib overhead on params table... this table is 16BG and  has 205mil records, i guess it may take hours to rebuild index or to fix the overhead

Comment: Explain, again, takes forever to run, 5 minutes of wait and nothing is shown. I have run explain the copy of the same DB but with a lot fewer data and explain shown 3 entries, as expected. Not sure on what is it you are looking for in the explain plan.

Comment: Could this also have something to do with lack of space on the HD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite query using LEFT JOINs to perform deletes. The reason why "exists" took too long is because "exists" has to check each record against the query.

Answer (score 0):

You simply perform `DELETE` on entire table if subquery returns any row:

```
DELETE FROM `records`;
```

I believe you want correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM `records`  
where exists (
  select * 
  from `measurements` 
  where `file_id` = 17
   and `measurements`.col_name = `records`.col_name 
) ;
```

**EDIT:**

> You are correct about correlation part. The query still taking DB down

You should check metrics (how many % of intital table you are removing). If more than 20-30% I would simply use `CTAs` and recreate table.

Second thing: you need to check FK (`ON DELETE CASCADE`)

Comment: You are correct about correlation part. The query is still taking DB down

Comment: I've just realised that both tables are MyISAM so ON DELETE CASCADE does not apply. In the test scenario, I was deleting 2155 rows. One table has 14mil records and the second table has 205mil records.  I find if I do query within exists() everything is ok. Same applies to when I delete a selection of record. However when I utilise exists() to do a selection or delete I have problems.